# Timing control in C# Socket Programming

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm currently getting started on a socket programming project for a University network planning course. I'm also doing a Programming class in which we are learning C# so I thought it appropriate to use C# to complete this assignment.

The assignment is to create a simple Server-Client connection and have data sent between them. That is not too much of a problem, I've read a few tutorials and watched a few videos and I think I know what I'm doing. That part which has me a little confused is  this:

"2) Every second, the server sends Client a command to seek measurement data, e.g., through a single letter "R" or "r" (request). (timing control is required here)."

This has me confused, What exactly is timing control? And how can I go about implementing it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I found an "example" of timing control, but it is in the C/C++, Do I need to do something liek this?

```
/* Step 5.2: Send and Receive Data in loops */
    time_old = getTime();
    iterationStep = 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        recvStatus = recv(TCPClient, recvBuffer,128,0);
        if(recvStatus == 0)
            break;
        else if(recvStatus == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Failed in recv(): %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        recvBuffer[recvStatus] = 0x00; /* '\0' */

        time_new = getTime();
        time_interval = time_new - time_old;
        time_old = time_new;

        printf("Step = %5d;     Time Interval = %8.6f;     Received String: %s\n", iterationStep,time_interval,recvBuffer);
        iterationStep++;
    }

    /* if "EXIT" received, terminate the program */
        if (!strcmp(recvBuffer,"EXIT"))
        {
            printf("TCP Server ready to terminate.");
            break;
        }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Im trying now to use this method but am having some trouble. I have created this method:

```
private static void SendRequest(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("WAAAAT");
        acc.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);

    }
```

But as you can see, I cannot use the "acc" socket because I can set it as a parameter. I tried to but then I get a lot of errors when calling the method, any advice?

Comment: Talk to your teacher if you have a question about a confusing assignment.  He knows the *exact* answer, little point in asking complete strangers on the Internet that know nothing about what you are supposed to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you will need to use the "System.Timers.Timer" class to execute your "send request" function every second.

Example:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create a timer with a one second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    aTimer.Elapsed += SendRequest;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void SendRequest(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // maybe end existing request if not completed?
    // send next request
}
```

Whether you time out(cancel) any existing requests before starting a new one will depend on your requirements as it is also possible to have many requests running in parallel.  If you do need to kill a request, you can do so by disposing the System.Net.Sockets.Socket that initiated the connection attempt (you will need to handle any errors thrown by the Socket.Connect).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do have a quick follow up though, I've added an edit to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Timing control sounds like a mechanism to insure that the requests are fired 1 sec apart and that if a request doesn't complete in a timely fashion to terminate that request and fire the next one.

Take a scenario

Request 1 fires at point 0 
After 1 sec request 1 hasn't received an answer but request 2 needs to fire.

You probably need to implement a timeout system based on a clock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any documentation/tutorial links that I could check out? thanks!